# How to assign lexical features to new unanalyzable tokens in spaCy?

Tags: spacy

I'm working with spaCy, version 2.3. I have a not-quite-regular-expression scanner which identifies spans of text which I don't want analyzed any further. I've added a pipe at the beginning of the pipeline, right after the tokenizer, which uses the document retokenizer to make these spans into single tokens. I'd like to remainder of the pipeline to treat these tokens as proper nouns. What's the right way to do this? I've set the POS and TAG attrs in my calls to retokenizer.merge(), and those settings persist in the resulting sentence parse, but the dependency information on these tokens makes me doubt that my settings have had the desired impact. Is there a way to update the vocabulary so that the POS tagger knows that the only POS option for these tokens is PROPN?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tagger and parser are independent (the parser doesn't use the tags as features), so modifying the tags isn't going to affect the dependency parse.

The tagger doesn't overwrite any existing tags, so if a tag is already set, it doesn't modify it. (The existing tags don't influence its predictions at all, though, so the surrounding words are tagged the same way they would be otherwise.)

Setting TAG and POS in the retokenizer is a good way to set those attributes. If you're not always retokenizing and you want to set the TAG and/or POS based on a regular expression for the token text, then the best way to do this is a custom pipeline component that you add before the tagger that sets tags for certain words.

The transition-based parsing algorithm can't easily deal with partial dependencies in the input, so there isn't a straightforward solution here. I can think of a few things that might help:

- The parser does respect pre-set sentence boundaries. If your skipped tokens are between sentences, you can set `token.is_sent_start = True` for that token and the following token so that the skipped token always ends up in its own sentence. If the skipped tokens are in the middle of a sentence or you want them to be analyzed as nouns in the sentence, then this won't help.
- The parser does use the `token.norm` feature, so if you set the `NORM` feature in the retokenizer to something extremely PROPN-like, you might have a better chance of getting the intended analysis. For example, if you're using a provided English model like `en_core_web_sm`, use a word you think would be a frequent similar proper noun in American newspaper text from 20 years ago, so if the skipped token should be like a last name, use "Bush" or "Clinton". It won't guarantee a better parse, but it could help.
- If you using a model with vectors like `en_core_web_lg`, you can also set the vectors for the skipped token to be the same as a similar word (check that the similar word has a vector first). This is how to tell the model to refer to the same row in the vector table for `UNKNOWN_SKIPPED` as `Bush`.

  1. The simpler option (that duplicates the vectors in the vector table internally):

  ```
  nlp.vocab.set_vector("UNKNOWN_SKIPPED", nlp.vocab["Bush"].vector)
  ```

  2. The less elegant version that doesn't duplicate vectors underneath:

  ```
  nlp.vocab.vectors.add("UNKNOWN_SKIPPED", row=nlp.vocab["Bush"].rank)
  nlp.vocab["UNKNOWN_SKIPPED"].rank = nlp.vocab["Bush"].rank
  ```

  (The second line is only necessary to get this to work for a model that's currently loaded. If you save it as a custom model after the first line with `nlp.to_disk()` and reload it, then only the first line is necessary.)
- If you just have a small set of skipped tokens, you could update the parser with some examples containing these tokens, but this can be tricky to do well without affecting the accuracy of the parser for other cases.

The `NORM` and vector modifications will also influence the tagger, so it's possible if you choose those well, you might get pretty close to the results you want.